# How to Properly Get the new Foreign Key Value Of Parent Id when Cloning object in EF core

Tags: c#, linq, generics, cloning

Given that Model

```
   public class Record
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public int? ParentId { get; set; }
   }
```

Record before cloning

```
            // here is the Records List Before Cloning ClonedRecords
            //    Id        ParentId
            //    ---       --------
            //     1         null 
            //     2          1
```

Method to clone records

```
static List<Record> Clone(List<Record> records)
    {
        var clone = new List<Record>();
        foreach(var item in records)
        {
            clone.Add(new Record {
               Title = item.Title,
               ParentId = null  // I  want to Map the ParentId to the new created add and not the old value
            });

        }
    }
```

My Question is In the Cloned Version i would like to get a new ParentId value based on the ParentId from the original records.

```
            // here is the Records List After Cloning ClonedRecords
            //    Id        ParentId
            //    ---       --------
            //     1         null 
            //     2          1 
            //     3         null 
            //     4          3
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You cannot add a parent if there is not a some parameter by which you can find it. If, after adding, he broke all communications with the old List<>.

2) you can add whole trees at once.

3) You can temporarily bind the id of the old and the new sheet for the duration of the copy.

The example below is not accurate, the main thing is logic. And you can use other arrays instead of dictionary.

```
static List<Record> Clone(List<Record> records)
{
    //for temprary save old_new id relationships
    Dictionary<int, int> temp = new 

    var clone = new List<Record>();
    foreach(var item in records)
    {
        var objtemp = new Record {
           Title = item.Title,
        };

        var rel = temp[x.item.ParentId];
        if(rel != null)
        {
            objtemp.ParentId = rel;
        }

        clone.Add(objtemp);
        //if id is sql identity you need savechanges()
        context.SaveChanges();

        temp.Add(item.id, clone.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the Records in your cloned list to have all values similar to one of the values in your original list, except for the Id. You want a new unique Id, which was not used in the original List.

### Short answer

```
public ICollection<Record> Clone(IEnumerable<Record> originals, IIdFactory idFactory)
{
    // First create a new Id for every original Record.
    // Put them in a dictionary for fast lookup
    IDictionary<int, int> idTranslator = originals.ToDictionary(
       record => record.Id
       record => this.IdFactory.CreateId());

    return originals.Select(original => new Record
    {
        Id = idTranslator[original.Id],
        ParentId = idTranslator[original.ParentId],

        ... // other properties
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

### Explanation

Every clone needs a proper unique new Id. So our method needs something to generate  unique Ids.

Let's first define an interface for an IdFactory:

```
interface IIdFactory
{
    int CreateId();
}
```

Every time you call Create, a new unique ID is created.
See below for a simple IdFactory

#### Create the clones

```
public ICollection<Record> Clone(IEnumerable<Record> originals, IIdFactory idFactory)
{
    // todo: decide what to do if originals == null

    // Before cloning, create a new Id for every clone
    // Put them in a dictionary for fast lookup
    IDictionary<int, int> idTranslator = originals.ToDictionary(
       record => record.Id
       record => this.IdFactory.CreateId());
```

So we  have a dictionary where keys are all Ids used in originals, and values are the Ids of the corresponding clones.

Start cloning; use the idTranslator to translate original Ids into clone Ids:

```
return originals.Select(original => new Record
{
    Id = idTranslator[original.Id],
    ParentId = idTranslator[original.ParentId],

    ... // other properties
})
.ToList();
```

Be sure to return the result as a List, not as an IEnumerable, after all, you'll lose the dictionary, hence you can't use it anymore after your return.

#### IdFactory

I don't know how you create your Ids, a simple factory could be:

```
class IdFactory : IIdFactory
{
    public IdFactory(IEnumerable<int> existingIds)
    {
        if (existingIds.Any())
        {
            this.nextId = existingIds.Max()+1;
        }
    }

    private int nextId = 0;

    public int CreateId()
    {
        int id = this.nextId;
        ++nextId;
        return id;
    }
}
```

But of course you can use your own IdFactory.

#### Usage

```
IEnumerable<Record> originals = ...
IIdFactory idFactory = new IdFactory(originals);    
var clones = Clone(originals, idFactory);
```

Comment: actually the unique id is taken care by ef core and it's generated as identity. what i want is for the cloned list i would like the parentId property to have the values of the new Generated Ids so the new parentId value for the cloned object will not point to the original record instead it will point to the new cloned object Id

Comment: My, why didn't you add entity framework to the flags. I could have explained it easier, now that I know your knowledge. By the way, I already reckoned that the ID was generated for you. See the Get only in the interface: you can't change it.